# Filtering multiple conditions with multiple variables using filter function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a dataset where I am trying to filter down some data before I start running operations on it.  However, I am having the following issues:

1. Up until using the select() I get all the data from the selected variables.
2. Once I attempt to apply filters on one variable it works showing the filtered data.  However, as soon as I attempt to do a second condition it prints out 0 observations.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I am trying to figure out if this is just semantically wrong or there some syntax issue I'm missing.  I have been searching and cannot find out the fix.  I feel like the issue has something to do with the logical operators but I cannot figure out what needs to go there.

The not equal operators are for specific "coded" values inside the data set.

The code:

```
select(X1, X2, X3, X4) %>%
filter(X1 != "97" &
       X1 != "98" &
       X1 != "99" &
       
       X2 != "88" &
       X2 != "77" &
       X2 != "99" &
       
     X3 != "88" &
     X3 != "77" &
     X4 != "99" & 
      
     !is.na(X1) 
     !is.na(X2)
     !is.na(X3) 
     !is.na(X4))
```

Comment: Use ``%in%`` instead. `filter(!X1 %in% 97:99 & !X2 %in% c(77, 88, 99) & !X3 %in% c(77, 88) & X4 != 99)`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I ran that and it's still not printing any variables.   I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @RonakShah. Thanks I will try to see if I can come up with an example.

Answer (score 1):

AS pointed by Rui Barradas in the comments, use `! x %in% y` instead of multiple (in)equality conditions.

You replied in a comment that was still not "printing any variables". If the function runs without errors, could it be that there are no observations left after filtering? Maybe you mean to use some `OR` operators for each of the variable chunks. See my second example if that works for you.

For the missing filter, I assume you mean to keep only the complete cases.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr) # for drop_na
vec <- c(NA, 80:99)
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  X1 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T), 
  X2 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T), 
  X3 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T), 
  X4 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T)) %>% as_tibble()

# filtering with AND between each variable

df %>% 
  filter(!(X1 %in% c(97, 98, 99)) &
           !(X2 %in% c(77, 88, 99)) &
           !(X3 %in% c(77, 88, 99)) &
           !(X4 %in% c(77, 88, 99)), 
  ) %>% drop_na() # will keep only complete cases, with valid obs for all rows 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       X1    X2    X3    X4
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1    83    98    96    98
#>  2    88    86    84    89
#>  3    82    81    80    81
#>  4    85    93    80    83
#>  5    82    86    84    80
#>  6    92    82    86    95
#>  7    93    83    95    92
#>  8    81    82    85    86
#>  9    87    80    82    86
#> 10    91    95    87    82

  
# filtering with OR between each variable
df %>% 
  filter(!(X1 %in% c(77, 88, 99)) |
           !(X2 %in% c(77, 88, 99)) |
           !(X3 %in% c(77, 88, 99)) |
           !(X4 %in% c(77, 88, 99)), 
  ) %>% drop_na() # will keep only complete cases, with valid obs for all rows 
#> # A tibble: 17 x 4
#>       X1    X2    X3    X4
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1    95    83    99    90
#>  2    83    98    96    98
#>  3    88    86    84    89
#>  4    82    81    80    81
#>  5    95    88    81    83
#>  6    93    89    99    92
#>  7    85    93    80    83
#>  8    82    86    84    80
#>  9    83    82    88    96
#> 10    92    82    86    95
#> 11    98    96    83    96
#> 12    93    83    95    92
#> 13    81    82    85    86
#> 14    87    80    82    86
#> 15    82    96    91    99
#> 16    83    81    88    82
#> 17    91    95    87    82
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To add on Marcelo Avila's answer, there is also `if_any` and `if_all` in {dplyr}. Note that you can also use `NA` inside `! .x %in% c(NA, 99, 88)`.

```r
library(dplyr) 
# data taken from Marcelo's answer
vec <- c(NA, 80:99)
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  X1 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T), 
  X2 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T), 
  X3 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T), 
  X4 = sample(vec, 20, replace = T)) %>% as_tibble()

df %>% 
  filter(!if_any(X1:X4, is.na),
         !if_any(X1:X2, ~ .x %in% c(97, 98, 99)),
         !X3 %in% c(88, 77),
         X4 != 99)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>       X1    X2    X3    X4
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1    95    83    99    90
#>  2    88    86    84    89
#>  3    82    81    80    81
#>  4    95    88    81    83
#>  5    93    89    99    92
#>  6    85    93    80    83
#>  7    82    86    84    80
#>  8    92    82    86    95
#>  9    93    83    95    92
#> 10    81    82    85    86
#> 11    87    80    82    86
#> 12    91    95    87    82
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>